# Does this spoof integral from a meme have a coherent solution $\int\frac {3x^3 -x^2 + 2x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I ask because I have what I think is a solution, but it doesn't fit the spirit of the joke, which is to say, it doesn't produce anything like a pin.[image: meme image]

The solution I get is the equation below:

$$-\frac{135\sqrt2\ln(3-2\sqrt2)+404}{16\sqrt2}$$

However, this solves to a transcendental number, beginning:

$$-2.98126694400553644032103778411344302709190188721887186739\cdots$$

So, I'm appealing for better or more informed solutions if I have made a mistake.

Does the equation solve to something nice and friendly, or is the whole thing just a wheeze?

Comment: This has bee asked and answered before.  Any help to find the dupe, other users?

Comment: According to https://www.integral-calculator.com/, the number you got is correct.

Comment: @amWhy Looks like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814179/how-to-integrate-the-product-of-two-or-more-polynomials-raised-to-some-powers-n

Comment: For confirmation of brute calculations, [WolframAlpha](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%283x%5E3-x%5E2%2B2x-4%29%2Fsqrt%28x%5E2-3x%2B2%29dx+from+0+to+1) ought to be your first stop.

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(3x%5E3-x%5E2%2B2x-4)%2Fsqrt(x%5E2-3x%2B2)+from+0+to+1) confirms your result

Comment: Thanks for the find, @DavidK, and RossMillikan !

Comment: Nice Solution...