# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{3x^3 - x^2 + 2x - 4}{\sqrt{x^2 -3x+2}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've got one integration question which I first felt was not a hard nut to crack. But, as I proceeded, difficulties arose. This is the one:

> $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{3x^3 - x^2 + 2x - 4}{\sqrt{x^2 -3x+2}}dx}$

I went ahead simplifying the two expressions and ultimately I reached this step:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x-2}} \ (3x^2 + 2x + 4) \ dx}$

I don't now what to do now, had I followed the correct pathway? Is there any other simpler method?

Comment: The substitution $y=\frac{x-1}{x-2}$ will rationalize the integrand.

Comment: I'm sure this'll be messy, but this looks like a good fit for a [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution).

Comment: See also: [Problem about evaluating $\int_0^1 {3x^3 -x^2 +2x -4\over \sqrt {x^2-3x+2} } \; dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3336353), [How do you evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(3x^3-x^2+2x-4)}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3474604), [How to integrate the product ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2814179) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2814179)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a hyperbolic substitution:
$$\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}=\sqrt{\Bigl(x-\frac{3\strut}2\Bigr)^{2}-\frac94+2}=\frac12\sqrt{(2x-3)^2-1},$$
so you can set, for $t\ge 0$,
$$2x-3=\cosh t\iff x=\frac{\cosh t+3}2,\qquad\mathrm dx=\frac12\sinh t\,\mathrm dt.$$
and the denominator of the integrand becomes $\;\frac12\sinh t$.

After you've simplified, you should obtain the integral of a cubic polynomial in $\cosh t$.

Comment: I completely understood your initial step, but when you came to $\cosh(?)$, I became a bit upset because I don't know why you did this, what was the reason? Method? as I'm a grade 12 student!

Comment: The idea is to remove the square root using a functional identity. For instance, in high school, it's quite common  to remove the square root in $\sqrt'1-x^2}$ setting $x=\sin t$ ($-\pi/2\le t\le\pi/2$), because of Pythagoras' identity $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$, s that $\:\sqrt{1-x^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2t}=\sqrt{\cos^2t}=|\cos t|=\cos t$ since $t$ lies between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/ 2$.  Here I simply used the analogous identity for hyperbolic functions: $\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$.

Comment: Oh my God, yes, I got this now, after trying and trying and trying!!! THANKS!, The more I appreciate your efforts, the less my appreciation goes.....

Answer (score 2):

It can be seen easily that for $H\left( x \right)=\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}-3x+2}$ 
$$\begin{align}
  & {{\left( {{x}^{2}}H\left( x \right) \right)}^{\prime }}=\frac{6{{x}^{3}}-15{{x}^{2}}+8x}{2H\left( x \right)}, \\ 
 & {{\left( xH\left( x \right) \right)}^{\prime }}=\frac{4{{x}^{2}}-9x+4}{2H\left( x \right)}, \\ 
 & {{\left( H\left( x \right) \right)}^{\prime }}=\frac{2x-3}{2H\left( x \right)} \\ 
\end{align}$$
This suggests that there exists $a,b,c\ and\ d$
$$\frac{3{{x}^{3}}-{{x}^{2}}+2x-4}{H\left( x \right)}=a{{\left( {{x}^{2}}H\left( x \right) \right)}^{\prime }}+b{{\left( xH\left( x \right) \right)}^{\prime }}+c{{\left( H\left( x \right) \right)}^{\prime }}+\frac{d}{H\left( x \right)}$$
Hence
$$\frac{3{{x}^{3}}-{{x}^{2}}+2x-4}{H\left( x \right)}=a\frac{6{{x}^{3}}-15{{x}^{2}}+8x}{2H\left( x \right)}+b\frac{4{{x}^{2}}-9x+4}{2H\left( x \right)}+c\frac{2x-3}{2H\left( x \right)}+\frac{d}{H\left( x \right)}$$ 
Or
$$3{{x}^{3}}-{{x}^{2}}+2x-4=\frac{a}{2}\left( 6{{x}^{3}}-15{{x}^{2}}+8x \right)+\frac{b}{2}\left( 4{{x}^{2}}-9x+4 \right)+\frac{c}{2}\left( 2x-3 \right)+d$$
Equating the coefficients yields 
$$\begin{align}
  & a=1 \\ 
 & -15a+4b=-2 \\ 
 & 8a-9b+2c=4 \\ 
 & 4b-3c+2d=-8 \\ 
\end{align}$$
and we get
$$a=1,b=\frac{13}{4},c=\frac{101}{16},d=\frac{135}{16}$$
Finally 
$$\int{\frac{3{{x}^{3}}-{{x}^{2}}+2x-4}{H\left( x \right)}dx={{x}^{2}}H\left( x \right)}+\frac{13}{4}xH\left( x \right)+\frac{101}{16}H\left( x \right)+\frac{135}{16}\int{\frac{dx}{H\left( x \right)}}$$