# How to evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{3x^3-x^2+2x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}~dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the best method with which to approach the following integral?

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{3x^3-x^2+2x-4}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}dx$$

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Instead of adding a photo, please use MathJax!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2983145/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: See also: [Problem about evaluating $\int_0^1 {3x^3 -x^2 +2x -4\over \sqrt {x^2-3x+2} } \; dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3336353), [How do you evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{(3x^3-x^2+2x-4)}{\sqrt{x^2-3x+2}}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3474604), [How to integrate the product ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2814179) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/2814179)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the substitution $$\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}=\pm x\sqrt{a}+t$$
It is the so-called Euler Substitution.